# How to setup sidebar modules to use jQuery Accordian

Tags: theme-development, sidebar

To use jQuery UI accordion, I need markup like

```
<h3>Module 1</h3>
<div>
   <!-- module content here -->
</div>


<h3>Module 2</h3>
<div>
   <!-- module content here -->
</div>

...
```

How can I setup my side bar like that? Or perhaps I somehow change the way jQuery creates accordian, maybe there are some options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your sidebar, you can change how it handles those things with the `before_title`, `after_title`, `before_widget`, and `after_widget` arguments. For example:

```
register_sidebar(array(
  'before_widget' => '',
  'before_title' => '<h3>',
  'after_title' => "</h3>\n<div>",
  'after_widget' => '</div>'
));
```

Would make all of the widgets in that sidebar have that structure. You could also add classes to the tags defined there (`<h3 class="accordion-toggle">`, `</h3>\n<div class='accordion-content'>`). Just make sure all your widgets have a title; otherwise the widget will cause some tag imbalance.